# Get first day of next and previous month in JSTL

Tags: jsp, date, jstl

I have to show first date of next and previous month, is there any way I can get it using JSTL. Pure JSTL is preferred.

I could get tomorrow as below.

```
<jsp:useBean id="ourDate" class="java.util.Date"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="ourDate" property="time" value="${ourDate.time + 86400000}"/>
<fmt:formatDate value="${ourDate}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
```

I couldn't get the first day of month.

Comment: check my latest edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSTL has only tags to [parse](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/parseDate.html) and [format](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatDate.html) the date, not to manipulate the date. Your best resort is EL (those `${}` things). Since Servlet 3.0 / EL 2.2 it supports method expressions in JSP as well. You could then use among others `Calendar#set()` and `Calendar#add()` methods. True, this is hacky, but as you asked for "pure JSTL", that's best you can get.

```html
<jsp:useBean id="firstDayOfMonth" class="java.util.GregorianCalendar">
    ${firstDayOfMonth.set(5,1)}
</jsp:useBean>
<jsp:useBean id="firstDayOfPreviousMonth" class="java.util.GregorianCalendar">
    ${firstDayOfPreviousMonth.set(5,1)}
    ${firstDayOfPreviousMonth.add(2,-1)}
</jsp:useBean>
<jsp:useBean id="firstDayOfNextMonth" class="java.util.GregorianCalendar">
    ${firstDayOfNextMonth.set(5,1)}
    ${firstDayOfNextMonth.add(2,1)}
</jsp:useBean>
```

*(those expressions are merely for self-documentary purposes nested inside the `<jsp:useBean>`, they can be placed outside, but it may be more confusing for starters; the first argument (`5` resp. `2`) is by the way value of the constant field `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` and `Calendar.MONTH`)*

Now you can present them as below via `Calendar#getTime()` the usual way:

```html
<fmt:formatDate value="${firstDayOfMonth.time}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
<fmt:formatDate value="${firstDayOfPreviousMonth.time}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
<fmt:formatDate value="${firstDayOfNextMonth.time}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
```

If you're not on EL 2.2 yet, then your best bet is preparing them in a servlet.